# R svyby gives error but svytotal works

Tags: r

I am creating descriptive statistic of 
a dataset and when I run the following it works

```
svytotal(~interaction(w4_prov2011,w4_c_grcurtyp),design=LFCP4.W,na.rm=TRUE)
```

but the following gives an error

```
svyby(~w4_c_grcurtyp,~w4_prov2011,design=LFCP4.W,svytotal,na.rm=TRUE)
```

> Error in tapply(1:NROW(x), list(factor(strata)), function(index) { :
>   arguments must have same length

Is that possible?